# Sharing state between multiple functions on the prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, eclipse-rap

I am creating a client side remote object in Eclipse RAP using Javascript for a text widget. I am then adding functions to the object's prototype in order to be handle various events and to do other business logic. Now some of these functions need access to the text widget.

Assuming that `init()` is always the first function invoked. I am wondering if it would be a good idea to store the text widget on the `TextObject`'s prototype? Are there any better ways to achieve this?

Edit: Another thought I had was to pass the text widget to every function which needs it but I don't like that either.

```
function TextObject() { }

TextObject.prototype = {

   widget:null,

   init: function(text)
   {
      this.widget = text;
   },

    incrementNumber:function() 
    {
       if(this.widget!=null)
       let textString = this.widget.getText();
    }
};
```

Comment: adding `widget` to the prototype means there would be a *single copy of it*. So, if you have two instances of `TextObject`, they'd be writing to the same `widget` property.

Comment: @VLAZ would it be ok to add it to the `TextObject` constructor and store the state there?

Comment: Possibly. To be honest, I'm not sure what problem are you trying to solve here, however, *usually* if you want to "share state between methods" you use the *object instance* for that. That's basically the reason to have objects - they hold the state that multiple methods will share between themselves.

Comment: @VLAZ, the constructor here will be invoked from the java server side when the remote object is first created. As far I know, given how remote objects are modeled in `RAP` I shouldn't create a `TextObject` instance within the client side source.